# Yii2 autoload Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube-api, yii2, youtube-data-api

I was trying to include youtube API in my controller. I have unzipped the Google youtube api in this path

```
     app\components\Google
```

Now what should i do to include all Google YouTube api files. When i create object of **Google_Client**
it says that **Google_Client class not found**. I know that File is not including but when i also try to include it via

```
    require(Yii::$app->basePath.'/components/Google/Client.php)
```

Again Same error comes class not found any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to use it, added the repository URL in `composer.json`.

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
```

After that just ran the command of `composer update`, composers copies that repo in my vendor folder. So i can just now use `use \Google\Client` namespace to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to use its namespace like below:

```
use path\Google_Client;
```

Comment: I've also tried that, because google is using Google_ prefix before each class, and on the file names there is no Google_ prefix. so should i add Google_ prefix in all the class files names ?

Comment: No dear, this is not about file names. Just, use app\components\Google_clients would be sufficient